# How to share Internet connection with Ubuntu Virtual Machine?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualization, virtualbox

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 as host and Installed Ubuntu 11.04 as Virtual Machine using Virtual Box. My proxy is configured using URL. I tried configuring in the networking settings and also with Firefox's preference page. But both did not work. How to solve this issue? I have configured the VM using default NAT option.

[image]

Comment: If you are in NATed mode, proxy configuration is not needed as it will not be able to see traffic coming from Guest OS(Ubuntu) directly. It will see traffic from Host OS(Windows) which is doing on behalf of Guest OS.

Comment: Have you confirmed connectivity to your proxy?

Comment: host is able to connect to the internet with the preferred configuration but the guest can't detect it I guess. I changed to No Proxy configuration but still it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Switch the network adapter (in VMWare or Virtualbox) to use bridged mode.  Then the VM will get a DHCP address from your home router directly, rather than from the vm internal NAT DHCP server,  and it will have the same access as the computer that is running the virtual machine.

Comment: I tried bridging as well. I think the virtual interfaces aren't up! It's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

[Enabling DNS proxy in NAT mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat-adv-dns)
Works for me.